# Botón centrar mapa en posición actual Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css, google-maps

Hay alguna manera de poner el típico botón de centrar via javascript o HTML en un google maps API v.3?

He buscado en la documentación pero no he sabido encontrar nada, por lo que he intentado hacerlo manualmente via css con `position` y `z-index`:

**HTML**

```
<div id="map-canvas" class="map">
    <button class="center__map__button" onclick="centraMapa()">CENTRAR</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.map {
    min-height: 100%; 
    position: relative;
}

.center__map__button {
    position:absolute;
    top: 300;
    left: 300;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Esto funciona como se puede ver en [**ESTA DEMO con un div normal**](https://js.do/code/110915), pero no me cuando lo hago con uno que dentro tiene un googlemaps, me sale antes de que cargue el mapa, pero después el mapa lo tapa.

Comment: En la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom?hl=es-419) de Google Maps lo dice.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas hacer no lo puedes hacer solo por clases, como lo dicen en un comentario arriba google pone a tu disposicion como hacerlo en su documentacion. Puedes ver en este codigo que se puede definir controles y su comportamiento, y tambien su apariencia, pero como estara dentro del mapa debes hacerlo como un control del mapa. Saludos aqui el codigo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom controls</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
var map;
var centro = {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65};

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function CenterControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Estilos para el contenedor. Haciendo uso de estos estilos puedes ubicar el boton donde desees y que se vea como desees
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  //Estilos para el interior del contenedor.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.innerHTML = 'Center Map';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Definir el eventListener: Cuando hacen click en tu control seteas el centro
  controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.setCenter(centro);
  });

}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: centro
  });
  
  var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
  var centerControl = new CenterControl(centerControlDiv, map);

  centerControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&signed_in=true&callback=initMap" async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Claro, debes usar un API_KEY